# Stop infinite get in Selenium WebDriverwhen using a proxy

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

UPDATE:

The reason for get(url) never finishing when i used a proxy what that some https parts of the website, (ad networks etc) did not like the proxy. thats why the page never really finished loading (actually it did, it just took unusually long)

I use Selenium Webdriver with Firefox, and when I try to access certain websites that load indefinitely (unless there is some kind of user interaction), I just want to prevent them from loading forever. I use the Java library of Webdriver, but code in Jython (hence no ';' or 'new xxx').

I tried

```
driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
driver.manage().timeouts().setScriptTimeout(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
driver.get(...)
driver.close()
```

but each time the get just won't stop.

I use DesiredCapabilities to start by browser via a proxy:

```
proxyServer = '127.0.0.1:8080'
proxy = Proxy()
proxy.setHttpProxy(proxyServer)
proxy.setSslProxy(proxyServer)
capabilities = DesiredCapabilities()
capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.PROXY, proxy)
driver = FirefoxDriver(capabilities)
```

When i don't set a proxy, the website is processed normally. only when using a proxy the website will stall and never finish the get(). This is no problem for every site, only *some* sites have this problem.

Any idea what can cause this? It seems the proxy settings prevent a message for either the browser or selenium to issue a signal that get() is completed.

Comment: Never ending get? Like what? When you actually open this page in your browser it never ends loading? I would consider this a as bug of the webpage.

Comment: When I use get(url) and follow up with for example a simple print("Hello World"), the print is never reached. When the webpage is buggy, I want to browser to say "ok lets stop this" and throw an exception for example.

Comment: it seems that setting a proxy causes this problem. it is only a problem on certain websites though. i don't know if i can name one example here.

Answer (score 0):

You could wait for 30s for an element, e.g. HTML tag, on the page to load. If the element doesn't load in 30s, catch the exception and move on.

```
try
{
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.tagName("html")));
}
catch (TimeoutException e)
{
    // do something when this exception is caught
}
```

Comment: i would do that, but the get(url) never finishes. however, i figured out what my problem was. some parts of the website, ad and click hosters, didn't like that there was no direct https connection between them and the website. that is why the site never really finished loading when i used a proxy